# Unable to connect to outlook.office365.com for processing emails with Perl Module Mail::IMAPClient

Tags: perl, outlook, office365, imap, mail-server

I have searched for days but finally run out of options, one of my clients move its emails accounts to **"outlook.office365.com"**, now all my perl scripts fails because they have a different set of configurations on their platform, so i had to rewrite all of my perl scripts to make everything work again, i was aible to send emails with the module **"Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS"** but i didnt had the same luck using my old modules to read and proccess emails such as **"Mail::POP3Client"**.

This is the code a try:

```
use Mail::IMAPClient;
use Email::MIME;

my $username = 'user';
my $password = 'pass';
my $server = 'outlook.office365.com';


print "Anon connect to IMAP\n";
my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
    Server => $server,
    Username => $username,
    Password => $password,
    Port => 993,
    Ssl => 1,
    Authmechanism => "PLAIN",
    Debug => 1,
)or die "Cannot connect to $mailhost as $username: $@";

print "upgrading connection to TLS \n";
$imap->starttls
(
    SSL_verify_mode => 0,
) or die "starttls failed: $@\n";

$imap->User($username);
$imap->Password($password);

print "Logging In\n";
$imap->login() or die "imap login failed: $@\n";
```

This is a solution that i have found on stackoverflow but it doesnt work for me, i checked my firewall configuration and everything is ok.

This is the output:

```
Anon connect to IMAP
Started at Fri Dec 16 13:54:25 2016
Using Mail::IMAPClient version 3.38 on perl 5.022001
Connecting with IO::Socket::SSL PeerAddr outlook.office365.com PeerPort 993 Proto tcp Timeout 600 Debug 1
ERROR: Unable to connect to outlook.office365.com:  at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Mail/IMAPClient.pm line 370.
        Mail::IMAPClient::connect(Mail::IMAPClient=HASH(0xcac170)) called at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Mail/IMAPClient.pm line 314
        Mail::IMAPClient::new("Mail::IMAPClient", "Server", "outlook.office365.com", "Username", "user", "Password", "pass", "Port", 993, ...) called at dont.pl line 10
Cannot connect to  as user: Unable to connect to outlook.office365.com:  at dont.pl line 10.
```

To check my SSL connection:

```
openssl s_client -connect outlook.office365.com:993
```

Results:

```
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
```

So any ideas?, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Maybe the message returned by the module is unclear? You could try to split: create the object first, then connect, then authenticate. In addition, if your already have the object, the module documentation tells that you can access to more errors.

Comment: There might be something: when I use your code without the username and password, I can see the "Read:   * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. " line. Are you sure of your credentials?

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't connect, but the `starttls` call is redundant and will cause an error as well: your connection is already secure.

Comment: It looks like it fails in `IO::Socket::SSL->new`. Please run your code with `perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4` to get more details what goes wrong and add these to the question. Also it might help if you add the versions of the modules (IO::Socket::SSL, Mail::IMAPClient) and of Perl to the question.

Comment: I tried different ways of how to connect and this was the more logical and recomended way, i have change the order of connection and authentication and got the same result, i didnt add starttls but i still got the same result, i activate debug4 to the IO::Socket::SSL Module but i dont see any new output. Module Versions IO::Socket::SSL = 2.039 ,  Mail::IMAPClient = 3.38.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: thanks to Max, finally a solution: removing startls allows to reach the login step.

```
use Mail::IMAPClient;
use Email::MIME;

my $username = 'user';
my $password = 'pass';
my $server = 'outlook.office365.com';


print "Anon connect to IMAP\n";
my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
    Server => $server,
    Port => 993,
    Ssl => 1,
    Authmechanism => "PLAIN",
    Debug => 1,
)or die "Cannot connect to $mailhost as $username: $@";

$imap->User($username);
$imap->Password($password);

print "Logging In\n";
$imap->login() or die "imap login failed: $@\n";
```

On my machine, it outputs this:

```
Anon connect to IMAP
Started at Fri Dec 16 16:59:31 2016
Using Mail::IMAPClient version 3.38 on perl 5.022001
Read:   * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [RABCADYAUABSADAAMgAwADEAQwBBADAAMAAyADcALgBlAHUAcgBwAHIAZAAwADIALgBwAHIAbwBkAC4AbwB1AHQAbABvAG8AawAuAGMAbwBtAA==]
upgrading connection to TLS 
Sending: 1 CAPABILITY
Sent 14 bytes
Read:   * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
        1 OK CAPABILITY completed.
Logging In
Sending: 2 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
Sent 22 bytes
Read:   +
Sending: [Redact: Count=2 Showcredentials=OFF]
Sent 18 bytes
Read:   2 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
ERROR: 2 NO AUTHENTICATE failed. at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Mail/IMAPClient.pm line 3261.
        Mail::IMAPClient::authenticate(Mail::IMAPClient=HASH(0x14f6a30), "PLAIN", undef) called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Mail/IMAPClient.pm line 562
        Mail::IMAPClient::login(Mail::IMAPClient=HASH(0x14f6a30)) called at imapt.pl line 30
imap login failed: 2 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

Which is normal, as I don't have a valid account.

Comment: You can fix the error here by removing the `starttls` call which is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that, for this module, setting the Ssl option is implcitely using TLS? that would make sense as SSL is considered obsolete.

Comment: I doubt that this solves the OP problem. According to the error message it is failing inside the `Mail::IMAPClient::connect` called from `Mail::IMAPClient->new` already, i.e. the (wrong) starttls is never reached. Looking at the source of `connect` it fails in `IO::Socket::SSL->new` but unfortunately Mail::IMAPClient does not propagate the exact errors from this stage to the user.

Comment: Well, then I'm dry. I hope someone find what the problem is. thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes, setting SSL begins the connection as SSL/TLS.  StartTLS upgrades an existing connection.

Comment: You and Stefen Ullrich don't seem to agree.

Comment: I'm referring to your solution; the original poster is having some other issue before getting here.

Comment: I have tried removing **starttls** but it didnt work @DavidVerdin, it seems that the only way to fix it is to try upgrading the connection with **TLS** of somehow...

Comment: Oh. You did run my exact script and it did not work?

Comment: No, It did not work, i checked my credencials directly on outlook and it works fine, i really dont know what else to do!